# Do The Karate Kid animated series share continuity with The Karate Kid franchise?

Tags: chronology, karate-kid, karate-kid-tv

I used to watch [*The Karate Kid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Karate_Kid_(TV_series)) animated series back then but I never got to understand if it shares continuation with other live action films or not.

What is the case? Is it canon to films or a spin-off scrapping canon?

Comment: Same wikipedia article states that **It is based on the Karate Kid series of films** and it's linked to 1984 movie

Comment: @Vishwa based on doesn't signify continuity. Mask TV series is based on film but contradict continuity

Answer (score 1):

The [cartoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Karate_Kid_(TV_series)) is a *continuation* of the 1984 film and features Daniel and Mister Miyagi, but the show is more of a 'fantasy adventure' format and not part of the main canon which consists of the four *Karate Kid* franchise films; *[The Karate Kid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Karate_Kid)*, *[The Karate Kid Part II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Karate_Kid_Part_II)*, *[The Karate Kid Part III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Karate_Kid_Part_III)* and *[The Next Karate Kid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Next_Karate_Kid)* but not the [2010 reboot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Karate_Kid_(2010_film)).

Jon Hurwitz, the director of the 2018 *[Cobra Kai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobra_Kai)* TV show, billed as a continuation of the film canon and a direct sequel to the prior films stated that **the cartoon series was, alas not part of the main canon of works** but that they did intend to include an 'easter egg' from the cartoon in their show. This turned out to be a small reference to Miyagi's shrine.

> **Q:** *It's a weird question, but is the Karate Kid animated series official within the Karate Kid / Cobra Kai universe?*
>
> **Jon Hurwitz:** ***The Karate Kid cartoon is not canon.** But there is an Easter Egg from it in Season 3*
>
> <sub><sup>[Per Twitter](https://twitter.com/jonhurwitz/status/1309356871073984512?lang=en-GB)</sup></sub>